# Python : Read .JS file without missing any data

Tags: python

I'm tring to read a '.js' file but when i try I can't read data same as I have in the js file some lines goes missing, can anyone please help.

The code I tried is

```
import json
file_path = 'C:/Users/smith/Desktop/inject.bundle.js'
with open(file_path,'r', encoding='utf-8') as dataFile:
    data = dataFile.read()
print(data)
```

The js file I tried is [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/venkatesanramasekar/jstesting/master/inject.bundle.js).

Answer (score 0):

Why not download the js file using a rest call?

```
import requests

res = requests.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/venkatesanramasekar/jstesting/master/inject.bundle.js")
data = res.text

// to save to a file
with open("inject.bundle.js", "w") as f:
     f.write(data)
```

Comment: I have the downloaded file, posted the link for reference here. The issue I'm facing here is when I read the data I cant read the data same as it in the file, half of the data goes missing.

Comment: Just confirm that you downloaded the file correctly. If you copy pasted the file, then there might be a chance of data loss

Comment: I have no data loss in downloading file, I have issues in reading the data, please help me in that if you can,